# What exactly is the cutoff for "low-dpi" devices when using the "px" unit in CSS?

Tags: css, frontend

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length), the "px" unit can mean 2 completely different things depending on whether it's on a "low-dpi" device or a "high-dpi" device.

> For low-dpi devices, the unit px represents the physical reference pixel; other units are defined relative to it.

or

> For high-dpi devices, inches (in), centimeters (cm), and millimeters (mm) are the same as their physical counterparts. Therefore, the px unit is defined relative to them (1/96 of 1 inch).

But how exactly does it differentiate one from another? What is the cut off for "high dpi"? How can I tell which one of these 2 cases is being used on a particular device?

Comment: That depends on the device. Many phones I've seen use a whole number of hardware dots per px, so they don't really have exactly 96 px per inch, even though they could. In fact the only devices where you measure things in inch rather than px (i.e. where 1px is simply 1/96 of an inch) are printers.

Comment: https://juiceboxinteractive.com/ideas/a-pixel-is-not-a-pixel-designing-new-generation-mobile-devices/

Comment: But the question is, does this matter? Is this an XY problem? Is there a specific situation that you need to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer on the w3 page:

> In the past, CSS required that implementations display absolute units correctly even on computer screens. But as the number of incorrect implementations outnumbered correct ones and the situation didn't seem to improve, CSS abandoned that requirement in 2011. Currently, absolute units must work correctly only on printed output and on high-resolution devices.
>
> CSS doesn't define what “high resolution” means. But as low-end printers nowadays start at 300 dpi and high-end screens are at 200 dpi, the cut-off is probably somewhere in between.

https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html